# How to convert Silverlight XAML to Resource dictionary in Silverlight 2

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-2.0

I am looking for the quickest and easiest way to combine two silverlight projects. Once has controls all in Silverlight XAML the other is template driven and uses a template based on a Silverlight resource dictionary. I am looking for some advice and resources on the best and quickest way to do this.

One project is based on this:

**Silverlight Image Slider**

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Image-slider-control-in-Silverlight-1.1.aspx

the other project is based on this:

**Open Video Player**

http://www.openvideoplayer.com/

I need to move the slider into the player, but the player uses a template and I just don't get how to merge the two as I do not understand resource dictionaries as they are applied to the player. We have completely gutted and made each proiject do what we want, but heck if I can figure out how to combine them.

Comment: Some sample code would help - it's unclear what the goal is. You should be able to move anything that was contained in an App.Resources (or any other RD) into a shared, merged resource dictionary.

Comment: Hard it's a crapload of code.  I will add some more info, hopefully it helps

Comment: OK, made edits with links to the controls i am using, if you looked at both you will understand what i am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answered all my questions, hope this helps someone else:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746927.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx